# Warning: Cannot record touch move without a touch start

Tags: react-native

i have this code that shows a list with the values of an array and i get a warning when i run the code

```
{this.state.ListCodeABarre.map((CodeABarre) => {
            return (
              <Item
                key={CodeABarre}
                style={{
                  alignSelf: "flex-start",
                  marginTop: 10,
                  marginLeft: 20,
                  width: 200,
                }}
              >
                <Body>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 17 }}> 
                  {CodeABarre}</Text>
                </Body>
                <Right>
                  <GradientButton
                    gradientBegin="#253f8e"
                    gradientEnd="#D02F30"
                    style={{ height: 30, width: 50, 
                    marginBottom: 4 }}
                    onPressAction= 
                    {this.removeOne(CodeABarre)}
                  >
                    <Icon name="window-close" size= 
                    {18} color="white" />
                  </GradientButton>
                </Right>
              </Item>
            );
          })}
```

actually the button on left is ment to delete the element of the table and so it will be removed from the list in the view but it's not working and it shows that error instead.

this is the function called in the delete button :

```
  removeOne(CodeABarre) {
    var array = this.state.ListCodeABarre; // make a separate copy of the array
    var index = array.indexOf(CodeABarre)
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({ListCodeABarre: array});
    }
  }
```

Comment: Help me understand, what is the problem? The warning or item not getting deleted?

Comment: Also, what is CodeABarre? Is it an object? Does it have an id or an unique field?

Comment: now both. after i added that function the items are not even being displayed anymore before it everything was working great i mean the list was adding items and working greatfully but i need that button to be able to delete the corresponding item from the list  "ListCodeABarre"

Comment: state = {
    ListCodeABarre: [],
  };   i'm mappin this array to display it and codeABarre is the actual item each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by manipulating that items list as an array in state so each time i just filter an item (passed in params of the function) from the state.array and it will disapear from the list of items like this :

this is my new function

```
 removeOne = async (CodeABarre) => {
    const newList = this.state.ListCodeABarre.filter((cb) => cb !== CodeABarre);
    await this.setState({ ListCodeABarre: newList });
  };
```

and here is the item where the function is being called

```
                   <Item
                    key={CodeABarre}
                    style={{
                      alignSelf: "flex-start",
                      marginTop: 10,
                      marginLeft: 20,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Body>
                      <Text style={{ fontSize: 17 }}>{CodeABarre}</Text>
                    </Body>
                    <Right>
                      <GradientButton
                        gradientBegin="#253f8e"
                        gradientEnd="#D02F30"
                        style={{ height: 30, width: 50, marginBottom: 4 }}
                        onPressAction={() => this.removeOne(CodeABarre)}
                      >
                        <Icon name="window-close" size={18} color="white" />
                      </GradientButton>
                    </Right>
                  </Item>
```